# Return a boolean if the first letter is a consonant or not

Tags: java, boolean

I've got a program that I am writing, it is suppose to translate words to pig latin (really basic exercise)
I can get the consonants to change to pig latin with no issue but the other side is that I need to check if the first letter is a consonant and if it's not then the translation changes.

I've built a method that checks if the first letter of a word is a consonant and if it is return a boolean as true otherwise false.

For some reason the method won't run the "else" statement

Here is the method that was written.

```
private static boolean firstLetterConsonant(String s)
{
    boolean isConsonant;

    //check to see if the first letter is not a vowel
    if(s != "a" && s != "e" && s != "i" && s != "o" && s != "u")
    {
        isConsonant = true;
    } else {
        isConsonant = false;
    }
    return isConsonant;
}
```

As a side comment the method is getting passed the string that was entered by the user elsewhere in the program.

Comment: You're not checking the first letter, you're checking the whole string.  `char c = s.charAt(0)`

Comment: @Techiee don't jump to conclusions.  I didn't downvote you ... until just now

Comment: @Tibrogargan: Sorry about that. @ Gendarme: I have written in answer, that he is comparing string instead of characters which i know is incorrect.

Comment: You have me wondering if there's a way to query a Locale (or some other Java class) to get an array of characters that are considered vowels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options.

1. Use `String#startsWith()` and an if condition checking for 5 vowels (just like what you are doing)
2. Take the first char out of the String using `String#charAt()` and check if it is a vowel (and return false if that's the case).
3. Use `String#matches` and use `"(?i)[^aeiou].*"`

Comment: last one misses capitals, no?.  Also, `-1 == "aeiou".indexOf(s.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase())` XD

Comment: @Tibrogargan - No. The `?i` option makes the matching case-insensitive. It checks for both capital and small chars.

Comment: You just snuck that in there :)

Comment: Thanks, I used the third method and I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do this way:

When you pass string value to this method you should check whether it is null or not null. Because if string value is null it will raise null pointer exception.

```
private static boolean firstLetterConsonant(String s)
{   
 char l = s.toLowerCase().trim().charAt(0);
 //check to see if the first letter is not a vowel
 if (l!='a' && l!='e' && l!='i' && l!='o' && l!='u')) {   
    return true;
 }
return false;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `else` block, if you initialize `isConsonant` with `false`.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @QBrute You don't even need `isConsonant`. `if(1!='a' [...]) return true; return false;`.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a quite simple solution.

```
private static boolean firstLetterConsonant(String s) {
    boolean isConsonant = true;

    if ("".equals(s))
        return false;

    //check to see if the first letter is not a vowel
    switch(s.charAt(0)) {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
        case 'I':
        case 'i':
        case 'O':
        case 'o':
        case 'U':
        case 'u': isConstant = false;
    }
    return isConsonant;
}
```

You were checking the String itself, but you should have checked only the first character.

---

Or you could have just used `String.matches` function and passed in `"(?i)[^aeiou].*"`. Regular expression is better.

Comment: You return `true` when the first letter is **not** a consonant.

Comment: Lol slipped out. Fixed it.